# Python - A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, vision

I'm trying to install google's vision API on my system. 
I'm using the command

> pip install --upgrade google-cloud-vision

On executing this command the following error is shown:

> ```
> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000005D77DA0>:
> ```
>
> Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachabl
>   e network',)': /simple/google-cloud-vision/
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-cloud-vision (from versions: ). No matching distribution found for google-cloud-vision

Please help. How can I solve the problem?

**Note:-
I had installed openCV through the .whl file and it installed just fine. But when I tried to install scikit-image through the same process, it shows the aforementioned error.**

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with source code? pls try .. google.cloud.vision.feature is one of the deprecated modules in v0.25.1 onwards. If you do not wish to migrate to the newest version you can force to use the old one with google-cloud-vision==0.25 in requirements.txt or using pip:

`pip install google-cloud-vision==0.25`

you can look [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/python-client-migration#deprecated_modules)  , may be somewhat usefull.

Comment: I'm guessing the error is with HTTPS connection. Is there any way I can force this connection through HTTP?